# Android studio still shows title on .noactionbar theme

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my style:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>`

and this is what I get in the render preview

[image]

can someone please tell me if i am doing something wrong or android studio is still a pile of trash. thanks.

Comment: And you assign on `AndroidManifest` for you activity? where you have that theme declared? what folder?

Comment: the generated ones. all i did was cange it from .darkactionbar to .noactionbar

Comment: Yes it happens in Android Studio preview when using API 22 but on device it will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try this

**values/themes.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Mytheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_green</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_dark_green</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
//on your activity

<activity
            android:name="com.example.MyApp.Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
</activity>
```

Comment: nope. didn't work. note IT WORKS ON THE DEVICE IT IS JUST HARD TO DESIGN AND PLACE STUFF WHEN IT LOOKS LIKE THIS IN ANDROID STUDIO

Comment: strange... did it works perfect on my app, Android 4.0+, show us more details on your question.

Comment: ? I'll explain: i mad an app with a regular activity in android studio. it is set to 4.0.3+, and I want to get rid of the action bar. So i changed it to .noactionbar but android studio still shows me the app name on top. when i run the app in avd it does not exist. i am wondering if this is more google BS or a issue with my code.

Comment: Before platform tools 22 it did not display it at all. so i am not shocked if Google still thinks we should enjoy their buggy software as the abandon the long standing eclipse platform.